# HSK 6 Writing: automatically saved?

Tags: hsk

I took the computer-based HSK 6 Test today. For the writing part, I was typing the entire time and did not notice there was a "save" button on top of the typing field until time was up. I never clicked on that button. I am wondering if it will automatically save and submit everything I typed. I am actually extremely worried right now... I don't want it to submit an empty text field...

Comment: Please post Chinese-language related questions on this website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with languages.

Answer (score 2):

Not pressing the "save" button **has nothing to do** with your test results, because everything you wrote is auto-saved the moment you finish the test. I actually passed the same test without pressing that with a score of 196... so feel comfortable!